# POSIX_SPAWN Faliure

Tags: c++, posix, parent-child, posix-api

```
#include<iostream>
#include<spawn.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[],char *envp[])
{
pid_t c1,c2;
int ret1,ret2,val;
ret1=posix_spawn(&c1,"t.cpp",NULL,NULL,argv,envp);
ret2=posix_spawn(&c2,"t.cpp",NULL,NULL,argv,envp);
wait(&val);
wait(&val);
cout<<"\n\nChild Process 1: "<<c1;
cout<<"\n\nChild Process 2: "<<c2;
cout<<"\n\n"<<ret1;
cout<<"\n\n"<<ret2<<"\n";
}
```

Above code creates 2 child processes and each process in supposed to execute t.cpp which is a simple hello world code in c++. But it doesnt execute it. In fact this code works without creating even t.cpp. Can anyone explain why is this happening and how to execute t1.cpp?

Comment: I also tried specifying "/home/t.cpp" in place of "t.cpp"

Comment: You cannot execute a C++ source program as it would be contained on a .cpp file. Compile and link, then execute the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way of creating new process:

posix_spawn(&Pid,"my_exe",NULL,NULL,argv,envp);

where my_exe is the executable file created after I build the program. In your case t will be the executable created after you build the program.

Comment: Yes i realized that. Thanks a lot.